# How to send form data with a POST request?

Tags: ruby, post, http-post, httparty, open-uri

I want to view and scrape job listings on the https://www.akzonobel.com/nl/careers/vacatures/ website. The country has to be "The Netherlands" and the Job level is "Entry level".

I'm using [httparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) to send a POST request but it keeps returning the initial 10 job listings. The correct response should be 3 job listings.

This is the code I'm using:

```
require 'httparty'
require 'nokogiri'

@base_url = 'https://www.akzonobel.com'

url = "#{@base_url}/careers/vacatures/"

data = {
  'ctl00$contentLeft$ctl01$ddlCountryExt' => 'NLD',
  'ctl00$contentLeft$ctl01$ddlJobLevelExt' => 'ENTRY_LEVEL'
}

response = HTTParty.post("#{@base_url}/nl/careers/vacatures/", :body => data)

html = Nokogiri::HTML(response)

jobs = html.xpath('//h3//a')

jobs.each do |job|
  puts job.text
end

puts jobs.size
```

Which returns:

```
Regional Demand Planner Nordeuropa (m,w)
Forecast Analyst - TiO2 Spend Area
PS Regional Manager APAC
Production leader
Engineering Administrator - Temporary
Procurement Manager EMEA
Business Analyst, Americas
HR Business Partner Supply Chain and R&D
AS Regional Manager
Business Information Manager
10
```

How can I send the form data needed to the site to get the correct response?

---

Update:

I've tried the following:

```
require 'httparty'
require 'nokogiri'

@base_url = 'https://www.akzonobel.com'

url = "#{@base_url}/careers/vacatures/"

data = {
  'ctl00$contentLeft$ctl01$ddlCountryExt' => 'NLD',
  'ctl00$contentLeft$ctl01$ddlJobLevelExt' => 'ENTRY_LEVEL',
  'ctl00$contentLeft$ctl01$ddlContinentExt' => 1,
  'ctl00$contentLeft$ctl01$ddlRegionEx' => 4,
  'ctl00$contentLeft$ctl01$ddlJobFamilyEx' => 45,
  'ctl00$contentLeft$ctl01$ddlBusinessUnitExt' => 22,
  'ctl00$contentLeft$ctl01$ddlJobLevelExt' => 1,
  'ctl00$contentLeft$ctl01$ddlCountryExt' => 1,
}

response = HTTParty.post("#{@base_url}/nl/careers/vacatures/", :body => data)

html = Nokogiri::HTML(response)

jobs = html.xpath('//h3//a')

jobs.each do |job|
  puts job.text
end

puts jobs.size
```

Unfortunately the result is exactly the same.

---

Update 2:

Here's the updated code:

```
require 'httparty'
require 'nokogiri'

@base_url = 'https://www.akzonobel.com'

url = "#{@base_url}/careers/vacatures/"

data = {
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlContinentExt' => 'C_EUROPE',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlCountryExt' => 'NLD',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlRegionExt' => 'Gelderland',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlRegionExt' => 'Limburg',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlRegionExt' => 'North Holland',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlRegionExt' => 'South Holland',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => 'General Management',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => 'Integrated Supply Chain',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => 'Sales & Marketing',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => 'RD&I',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => 'Support',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => 'Other',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => 'Lvl2_General Management',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => 'Manufacturing',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => 'HSE',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => 'Engineering',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => 'Procurement',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => 'Distribution & Logistics',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => 'Sales',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => 'Marketing',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => 'Lvl2_RD&I',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => 'Finance',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => 'IM',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => 'HR',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => 'Legal, IP & Compliance',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => 'Facilities',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => 'Lvl2_Other',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => '80200000',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => '80300000',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => '81900000',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => '81100000',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => '82000000',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => '81200000',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => '80700000',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => '80400000',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => '80500000',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => '80800000',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => '80900000',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => '82100000',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => '82200000',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => '81010000',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => '81020000',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => '81030000',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => '81040000',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => '81300000',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => '81410000',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => '81420000',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => '81430000',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => '81600000',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => '81700000',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt' => 'Lvl3_Other',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlBusinessUnitExt' => '52000100',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlBusinessUnitExt' => '52000200',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlBusinessUnitExt' => '52000300',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlBusinessUnitExt' => '52000900',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlBusinessUnitExt' => '53000010',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlBusinessUnitExt' => '53000013',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlBusinessUnitExt' => '53000020',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlBusinessUnitExt' => '53000022',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlBusinessUnitExt' => '53000026',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlBusinessUnitExt' => '53000033',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlBusinessUnitExt' => '53000038',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlBusinessUnitExt' => '53000041',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlBusinessUnitExt' => '53000054',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlBusinessUnitExt' => '53000055',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlBusinessUnitExt' => '53000056',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlBusinessUnitExt' => '53000061',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlBusinessUnitExt' => '53000063',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlBusinessUnitExt' => '53000100',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlBusinessUnitExt' => '53000300',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlBusinessUnitExt' => '53000900',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlBusinessUnitExt' => '53000901',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlBusinessUnitExt' => '51000000',
  'contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobLevelExt' => 'ENTRY_LEVEL'
}

response = HTTParty.post("#{@base_url}/nl/careers/vacatures/", :body => data)

html = Nokogiri::HTML(response)

jobs = html.xpath('//h3//a')

jobs.each do |job|
  puts job.text
end

puts jobs.size
```

Giving me the exact same result as before.

Comment: HTTParty is not the correct tool for this type of scraping. I'd use Mechanize unless JavaScript execution is required.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem can be solved by changing this piece of code to a loop that only outputs job.text 3 times.

so change this,

```
jobs.each do |job|
  puts job.text
end
```

to this,

```
for (i=0; i < 3; i++) {
 puts job.text
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are JavaScript calls triggered on setting the country/joblevel in the GUI. You have to explicitely set all the dropdowns’ values (`Continent`, `Region`, `Job Family`, `Business Unit`) to the values they were given after the NLD/EntryLevel were set: 1, 4, 45, 22 respectively.

Another thing is that the real controls are hidden, use Chrome Inspector to see that. The real controls have their `id` looking like:

```
contentLeft_ctl01_ddlCountryExt
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've updated the question with the new code I used. The result is the same unfortunately.

Comment: I don't really understand the answer. Could you please elaborate some more and/or provide an example?

Comment: Sorry, I can’t just because there is a lot of work to do. Open the page in Chrome Inspector, search for `contentLeft_ctl01_ddlCountryExt`. You’ll find that there are 18 controls with the names like `BLAH_contentLeft_ctl01_ddlCountryExt_BLAH`. You have to pass their values to your script, not the containers’ `ctl00$contentLeft$ctl01$ddlCountryExt`. The same for all six dropdowns.

Comment: I've updated the code, still the same. Could you take a closer look when you have some time?

Comment: It looks like you don’t understand what you are doing. Repeating the `a => b` lines inside the `data` hash simply overrides the previous declarations. You should set the proper `...-option-N` values.

Comment: Correct, I don't know what I'm doing, I'm a beginner, that's why I'm asking questions, so I can learn. `contentLeft_ctl01_ddlJobFamilyExt` has `45` options, looking at `Chrome Inspector > Network > XHR` there's a POST request which sends along all 45, that's why I did the same. It's better to get a clear answer or no answer at all. It's confusing for a beginner like me.